# access iif query do nothing when false

Tags: ms-access

My situation/problem:

```
TableA
id, postalcode, region
```

Criteria for the field i want to add value in (`postalcode`):

```
=IIf([tableA.Region]="Chicago","60064",[postalcode])
```

What i need to accomplish is an iif-query where:

In the field `postalcode` I check in the criteria if the field region equals `Chicago`. If so fill up the field with postalcode `60064` if not DO NOTHING

For the do nothing part I'm using the fields name, this is wrong?
am i using the criteria in the right field (the field i want to add?)
I'm using a selection query?

As you can see i'm a noob in access queries...

Can somebody give me the right iff statement?
Thx in advance,
D

Comment: That uses 60064 as the postcode for Chicaco, else it uses whatever the value of the [postcode] field is, so assuming that's what you mean by "do nothing" its perfectly fine, is there something wrong with it? if so, what?

Comment: I agree with Alex, this work just fine in a query, SELECT id, region, iif(region="Chicago", "60064", postalcode)
FROM tableA

Comment: I think you need to move your condition somewhere else, if you only want the update performed on rows where region = Chicago.  IIF isn't intended to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you bracket `table.Region` differently, or eliminate the brackets there entirely.

```
=IIf([tableA].[Region]="Chicago","60064",[postalcode])
=IIf(tableA.Region="Chicago","60064",[postalcode])
```

If that doesn't fix the problem you're trying to solve, tell us more about the problem.  If you're getting an error message, tell us what it says.

Taking a wild guess, that code as a field expression in a query will not give you an editable column in the query result set.  If you want to pre-load a column value based on your criteria, but then allow the user to change the value, use a form.  In the form's On Current event, load the value as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dead old post but I think this was what you wanted:

```
=Like IIf([tableA.Region]="Chicago","60064",'*')
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand,

> if not DO NOTHING

You need to return nothing if the condition is false.

What you need is the `WHERE` clause instead of `IIF`

Comment: Note that this is specifically applicable to this situation; "Select all the records if [table].[field] = [somevalue]". This is better accomplished by "SELECT [field] FROM [table] WHERE [field] = [somevalue]".

When the IIF is somewhere else, WHERE may not work. Your mileage may vary!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a NULL value in Postal Code if it's not Chicago?

=IIf([tableA].[Region]="Chicago","60064","")

Answer (score 0):

Please add another IIF query as OR

> IIf([Forms]![Run_Macro
>   Form]![ReturnType_DrpDwn]="Monthly",[Forms]![Run_Macro
>   Form]![Cmb_Per_Ending],#1/1/2010#)
>
> > IIf([Forms]![Run_Macro Form]![ReturnType_DrpDwn]="Quarterly",#1/1/2010#,#1/1/2025#)